# ASP.NET MVC 5 routing - create Html.ActionLink and parse ViewContext.RouteData.Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, razor-pages

I want to parse data from a URL string at ASP.NET MVC 5. Here are the important lines.

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@Html.ActionLink(Name, ActionName, new { id = 6, status = 1 })
```

Browers Line

```
http://localhost/somthing/6?status=1
```

`create.cshtml`:

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]     
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["status"]
```

The values from "id" is "6" but the value from "status" is null.

What I have to do get the "1" from the URL string?

Comment: Do you have status parameter in your action method? If you don't have it add to parameters and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few possibilities:

```
Request.QueryString["status"];
Request.Params["status"];
```

In .Net Core it seems like you have to use:

```
Context.Request.Query["status"];
```